# Convert Sql Server Query to MySql Server Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Good Morning

I am Trying to Convert Sqlserver Join to Mysql server Join , Anyone please help me on this

Sql Server Code

```
 Update @ABC   
  Set grpId = g.GroupId
  From @ABC, luGroup g
  Where typeWrd = g.GroupName  
  and g.GroupTypeId = @gtid
```

Description :

```
@Abc    -- temporary table
luGroup -- Normal Table
```

Please help me to Convert this code to Mysql , i shall be thankful to you

Thanks
Amandeep

Comment: Please post your table structure So I can help you.

Comment: Are `@ABC` and `@workA` meant to be the same table variable (not temp table)? Also, that's fairly bad original SQL Server code to start from. Whoever wrote it hasn't learnt that Standard SQL got explicit join syntax over a *quarter of a century ago* and any SQL database product you're likely to encounter these days has probably adopted *this* part of the standard decades ago.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Sorry , Now please check it I changed the code, Sorry again for Wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the update from clause

```
Update @workA a    
INNER JOIN luGroup g ON a.typeWrd = g.GroupName  
AND g.GroupTypeId = @gtid
Set grpId = g.GroupId
```

Answer (score 1):

Crudely...

```
Update @ABC   
  From @workA, luGroup g

  Set grpId = g.GroupId

Where typeWrd = g.GroupName  
  and g.GroupTypeId = @gtid
```

Comment: Add small explanation even though code is explanatory